# Basic javascript Fahrenheit/Celsius calculator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to do a Celsius/Fahrenheit conversion calculator, with a button for each conversion and the result being displayed in the appropriate textbox.  I must be missing something obvious here... I'm brand new to javascript and am just not getting it.  Here's what I have done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <title>Convert Fahrenheit and Celsius</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function convertToC() {
                    var fTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('fTemp').value);
                var cTempVal = (fTempVal - 32) * (5/9);
                document.getElementById('cTemp').value = cTempVal;
            }

            function convertToF() {
                var cTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cTemp').value);
                var fTempVal = (cTempVal * (9/5)) + 32;
                document.getElementById('fTemp').value = fTempVal;
            }
        // -->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="conversionForm">
    <table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Fahrenheit</td>
        <td><input name="fTemp" type="text"/></td>
        <td><button onclick="convertToC">Convert to Celsius</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Celsius</td>
        <td><input name="cTemp" type="text"/></td>
        <td><button onclick="convertToF">Convert to Fahrenheit</button></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Either it's not doing the calculation or it's just not displaying it in the textbox...  Can't figure out which.  Or maybe it's both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few errors. See this corrected **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Qbssd/)**.

1. Your input boxes were missing IDs that you were trying to reference with `document.getElementById`
2. Your HTML was improperly closed.
3. Your buttons were missing types which makes them [default to submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) when you really wanted just button
4. To prevent the form from actually being submitted you should return false.

**JavaScript**

```
    function convertToC() {
        var fTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('fTemp').value);
        var cTempVal = (fTempVal - 32) * (5 / 9);
        document.getElementById('cTemp').value = cTempVal;
        return false;
    }

    function convertToF() {
        var cTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cTemp').value);
        var fTempVal = (cTempVal * (9 / 5)) + 32;
        console.log(fTempVal);
        document.getElementById('fTemp').value = fTempVal;
        return false;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="conversionForm">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Fahrenheit</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="fTemp" id="fTemp" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="convertToC();return false">Convert to Celsius</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Celsius</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="cTemp" id="cTemp" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="convertToF();return false">Convert to Fahrenheit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the DOM with the [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) function, but both `input` elements don't currently have an `id` attribute only a `name` attribute. So in your example, there are no elements that actually match the IDs you're passing to the function.

You should set the `id` attributes of both elements like so:

```
<input id="fTemp" name="fTemp" type="text">

<input id="cTemp" name="cTemp" type="text">
```