# Javascript: input and button. Function doesn't work -> Document.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript

Simple Code:

```
    <div id="right">
        <h2>Zamiana jednostek temperatury</h2>
        temperatura w <sup>o</sup>Celsjusza<br>

        <input type="text" id="cyfry" name="cyfry"><br>
        <button onclick="fahrenheit()">Fahrenheit</button>
        <button onclick="kelwin()">Kelwin</button>
        <span id="wynik"></span>
    </div>
```

And Script:

```
function fahrenheit(){
    var x=Document.getElementById("cyfry");
    parseInt(x);
    x = (x*1,8)+32;
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=x;
}
function kelwin(){
    var x=Document.getElementById("cyfry");
    parseInt(x);
    x = x + 273,15;
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=x;
}
```

As you can see all I want to do is convert units in Celsius to Fahrenheit or Calvins, but I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Document.getElementById is not a function
    at fahrenheit (script.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html?cyfry=:32)
```

Thanks a lot in advance and Happy New Year!

After some changes I have problem that answer is always 40 in Fahrenheit and 15 on Calvin:

```
function fahrenheit(){
    var x=document.getElementById("cyfry").value;
    parseFloat(x);
    var y = ((x*1,8)+32);
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=y;
}
function kelwin(){
    var a=document.getElementById("cyfry").value;
    parseFloat(a);
    var b = (a + 273,15);
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=b;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use document.getElementById **not** Document.getElementById . Heres a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function fahrenheit(){
    var x=document.getElementById("cyfry");
    parseInt(x);
    x = (x*1,8)+32;
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=x;
}
function kelwin(){
    var x=document.getElementById("cyfry");
    parseInt(x);
    x = x + 273,15;
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=x;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
        <h2>Zamiana jednostek temperatury</h2>
        temperatura w <sup>o</sup>Celsjusza<br>

        <input type="text" id="cyfry" name="cyfry"><br>
        <button onclick="fahrenheit()">Fahrenheit</button>
        <button onclick="kelwin()">Kelwin</button>
        <span id="wynik"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I will in 5 minutes, but I have another question, because now it's working, but everytime result is 40 when i click Fahrenheit, and 15 on the second button. Doesn't matter which value i type.

Comment: @Daniel the problem is in the math your applying. Please take a look at this  similar example. It will solve your question. Credit goes to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122347/basic-javascript-fahrenheit-celsius-calculator

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a case sensitive language. You have to use the uncapitalized `document`, not `Document`